# How do I monitor changes of files and only look at them when the changes are finished?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I'm currently monitoring files in node.js using [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener). The problem I have is for example, let say I copy a 1gig file into a folder I'm watching. The moment the file starts copying I get a notification about the file. If I start reading it immediately I end up with bad data since the file has not finished copying. For example a zip file has it's table of contents at the end but I'd end up reading it before it's table of contents has been written.

Off the top of my head I could setup some task to call `fs.stat` on the file every N seconds and only try to read it when the stats stop changing. That would work but it seems not ideal as I'd like my app to be as responsive as possible and calling stat on a bunch of files every second seems heavy as well as calling stat every 5 or 10 seconds seems unresponsive.

Is there some more robust way to get notified when a file has finished being modified?

Comment: Might be wrong, but isn't the "modified" date the last information that gets modified on a file after a change?

Answer (score 4):

So I did a project last year which required doing "file watching".  There is a better library out there than `fs.watch`.  Check out npm chokidar.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar

Underneath it uses fs.watch, but wraps better improvements around it.

There is a property called `awaitWriteFinish`.  Really it's doing some polling on the file to determine whether or not the file is finished writing.  I used it and it really works great.

Setting this property will allow you to work against that file, always ensuring that the file has been completely written.  And you don't need to go off and implement your own method of determining if the file is complete.  Should save a bunch of time.

Aside from that, I don't believe you can really get away from `polling` with regard to determining if a file is finished writing.  Chokidar is still polling, it's just that you don't need to write the logic to do it.  And you can configure the polling interval if CPU utilization is deemed to be too high.

Edit:  Would also like to add, to just give it a shot and see how it works.  I get you want it as responsive as possible... But having something working is better than having something not working at all.  It might be that even with a polling solution it's not even an issue for you.  If it's deemed a performance problem, then go address it at that time and seek a "better" solution.